# Sitecore PowerShell Extensions switch context language based on site context language

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have a script which loops over different sites in a Sitecore instance. For each site some tasks are done, such as creating and moving items. How can I set the language context for these operations based on the language set in the config for the current site (if this is not feasible, I would settle for using the language of the current item).

```
$sites = Get-Item master: -Query "fast:/sitecore/content/Master//*[@@templatename='Website']";
foreach ($site in $sites) {
    #determine the correct language of the $site item based off the sites configuration setting
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of your sites point to different items, here's what you can do:

```
$sitePath = $site.Paths.FullPath.Trim().ToLower()

$siteInfo =
    [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::GetSiteInfoList() |
        ? { ($_.RootPath.Length -gt 0) -and $sitePath -eq ($_.RootPath + $_.StartItem).ToLower() } |
        select -first 1

if($siteInfo -ne $null) {
    $language = $siteInfo.Language
    # ...
}
```

If your `$site` items can have multiple site definitions bound to them, then you have to use the language of the item:

```
$language = $site.Language.Name
```